# c# constructor issues (object is null)

Tags: c#

i been trying to link constructors but i been having issues as i have a lot of different classes witch share a lot of info with each other as so as it stands currently this is what i want to do

get one of the classes to reverence form1 so i can run a certain method

so this is what i have tryied so far

gscadding.cs

```
public SoundAlis sounds;
public addingweapons dlc3gsc;
public Form1 elfgsc;
public gscadding elfy;
private gscadding elfy1;
public gscadding(addingweapons dlc3)
{
    dlc3gsc = dlc3;
}

public gscadding(gscadding elfy1)
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    this.elfy1 = elfy1;
}
```

this is the class i want to get into form one to use a function i made in form 1

this is what i have in form1

```
elfenlied_program_settings elf;
addingweapons elf_weap;
Parser elfenliedl;
gscadding elfy;

//Parser parser = new Parser("model1887_sp");

public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    updater1.CheckForUpdates();
    listBoxAdv1.Visible = false;
    elf = new elfenlied_program_settings(listBoxAdv1,elfenliedl);
    elf_weap = new addingweapons(richTextBoxEx1);
    elfenliedl = new Parser("model1887_sp");
    elfy = new gscadding(elfy);
    timer1.Start();
    elf.buttonX2 = buttonX2;
    elf.elfenform = this;
   // elfe.elfgsc = this;
    buttonX2.Visible = false;
    buttonX3.Enabled = true;
    textBoxX6.Enabled = false;
    elfenliedl.buttonX1 = buttonX1;
```

basicly what im trying to do is form gscadding.cs to call a function called updatesettings();

witch when the form loads and i select a path it updates all string = paths

but i keep getting the

[image: Error I get]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This is very confuse. Why do you have an instance of gscadding inside of itself?

Comment: Please find a programming style for you and stick with it. That looks like you used an obfuscator before posting the source here.

Answer (score 1):

elfgsc is null you have to set it.

```
public gscadding(addingweapons dlc3, Form1 form)
    {
        dlc3gsc = dlc3;
        elfgsc = form;
    }
```

In your form constructor

```
elfy = new gscadding(elfy, this);
```

Now you can call methods in your form from your gscadding class like so:

```
elfgsc.updatesettings();
```

As to your second error, passing elfy to itself is useless. Remove elfy and replace with elfy_weap

Comment: i should have mentioned only just rememberd i have it in another cs as well here is a ghostbin of all the code  https://ghostbin.com/paste/hvrem
because it still gives me errors and i dont know why its not like i have not done this already multible times

Comment: Why are you passing elfy to itself? That doesn't make any sense. Remove 

public gscadding(gscadding elfy1)
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    this.elfy1 = elfy1;
}

Comment: See the second part of the answer to fix your new problem.

Comment: ok main form http://i.imgur.com/FtFDki3.png

gscadding
http://i.imgur.com/deArIcG.png changed things and still get does not exist in current contex error

Comment: You still have it a little backwards... In Form1 constructor it should be elfy = new gscadding(elf_weap, this);

Comment: yeah i did that and it still says null revrence in the error